# Facebook Ads Install Source Unknown & Facebook Ads App Install Testing Issue

Tags: android, facebook, ads

I wanted to track installs form facebook Ads for this i have followed steps mentioned [in this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-ads) and deployed app to playstore.

So issues i am facing in this are

1. How to add testers to test facebook ads so that my testers can checkout install are getting tracked properly.
   **Approach i used to test:** Through ad manager i have created ad in last step on button **View in Native App** i have tested functionality. Do my testers need to do same for testing ads.
2. I am getting install count properly but Facebook **Install Sources** are not getting tracked. I am getting value **Unknown** for **Install Sources**.
   **Note** : I havent placed order for ads my ad is still in development stage. Approach i used is same as in **1**

[image]

Comment: Did you ever discover why 'Install Sources' were marked as 'Unknown'?

Comment: @Bataleon We need to integrate https://www.appsflyer.com/ to track install source

Comment: Great. Thanks for the reply.